# P-value testing on data with known errors

Tags: statistical-significance, error, error-propagation

I have two cohorts, Long COVID vs control. They have been using a fitness tracking device for two months. I want to see if there's a significant difference in Sleep stages, Resting HR, and step counts. However, the fitness tracker I am using does not produce perfect results! How can I mitigate that?

More specifically, the fitness tracker I am using is

- 96 ± 7.8% accurate for 2-stage sleep detection
- 61 ± 9.2% accurate for 5-stage sleep detection
- 3.6 ±0.9 MAE for nocturnal HR monitoring
- 78 steps MAE/1000 steps for step counting

Comment: The error is independent of the test groups and subjects so any measurement error will “cancel out” between groups.  Of course the measurement error will cause more variability in the measured value, so in order to get your power back one has to increase the sample size.

Comment: By how much would I have to increase the sampling size?

Comment: You will need to perform a sample size calculation, there should be plenty of questions here related.  First you will need an estimate the sample variation and the desired resolution of a difference.  If you want to detect a difference in heart rate of 5 bpm then you will need a much larger small than if you want to detect a 50 bpm change.